# Как вставить значения в форму связанную с моделью

Tags: python, django, forms

Как в шаблоне установить занечения value в поля формы, связанной с моделью?
Есть ли возможность добраться до атрибутов инпутов?
Вот пример формы в шаблоне

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form form %}
        {% buttons %}
            <input type="submit" value="Бронировать">
        {% endbuttons %}
    </form>
{% else %}
    <p>Просьба <a href="{% url "login" %}">авторизироваться</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

Вот класс формы. В поля 'check_in_date', 'check_out_date' надо установить дату, чтобы пользователь не вбивал их вручную

```
from django import forms
from .models import Book


class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('customer', 'check_in_date', 'check_out_date', 'room')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/604325

Comment: А есть возможность передать значения из контроллера в форму?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

значит, варианты

для generic.Views - `View.get_form_kwargs()`

для форм - `Form(initial=dict(field_name=value)`

В первом случае переопределяете метод, чтоб возвращал словарь с initial для формы, а во втором - просто заранее передаете значения.

Так же можете запретить ввод данных в эти поля и поставить из в `clean()`, заменив данные в `cleaned_data` либо в при вызове `save()` метода. Так же есть сигналы `pre_save`, `post_save`.

Рекомендую воспользоваться способом через `initial` или `get_form_kwargs`, либо через `clean`/`save`

Подробнее можете почитать в документации по названиям методов